# Convert bios exe to bin file?

Tags: bios

I have an Alienware M18 R1, unfortunately I destroyed the BIOS, so there is only a black screen and the keyboard backlight is on, that's it. All key combinations don't work, even the USB slot for updating or flashing doesn't work. I urgently need BIOS firmware so that I can repair the BIOS with the USB programmer ch341a. Unfortunately Dell only offers exe files. Can someone help me with this or maybe even edit the biosexe?! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can simply extract it. That said, it's probably a waste of time anyway.